# How to resume closed tls conection with tokio-rustls

Tags: rust, tcp, rust-tokio, tls1.3

I want to send HTTP data multiple times to a server endpoint over the same TCP stream. However, after a period of sending and receiving data, I receive `0x00, 0x00`.

Using Wireshark, I discovered that the TLS session has been closed, but the TCP stream is still in a connected state due to Keep-Alive.

How can I reopen the TLS session to continue sending data over the existing TCP stream?

I checked the rustls documentation and found that "rustls::client::Resumption" might be relevant. However, I can't find any examples.

Attempting to reconnect to this TCP stream using TlsConnector results in a `tls handshake eof` error.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this? Thank you.